# How to expand macro within other macro's scope (trying to debug a macro)

Tags: macros, clojure

here is the simplest example I could make:

```
(defmacro printer [& forms]
  `(println ~@forms))

(defmacro adder [s]
  `(inc ~s))
```

They can be used as expected:

```
(printer "haha")
=> "haha"

(adder 1)
=> 2
```

And I can `macroexpand` them to see what the macro did:

```
(macroexpand '(printer 1))
=> (clojure.core/println 1)

(macroexpand '(adder 1))
=> (clojure.core/inc 1)
```

But when they are nested I don't get what I want:

```
(macroexpand '(printer (adder 1)))
=> (clojure.core.println (adder 1))
```

I was hoping to get

```
=> (clojure.core.println (clojure.core/inc 1))
```

Is there any way for me to expand nested macros?
That would help me a lot in debugging a specific bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are after [`macroexpand-all`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all)

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(macroexpand-all '(printer (adder 1)))
;(clojure.core/println (clojure.core/inc 1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thanks to you I did debug my bug :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for accepting my answer and I'm glad it helped. I forgot to add that if you want to fully expand what the compiler sees, you can harness the power of the clojure analyzer:

```
(use '[clojure.tools.analyzer.passes.jvm.emit-form :only [emit-form emit-hygienic-form]]
     '[clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm :only [analyze]])

(emit-form (analyze '(printer (adder 1))))

(emit-hygienic-form (analyze '(printer (adder 1))))
```

Both of the above give almost the same results as `macroexpand-all` but should cover corner cases where `macroexpand-all` may not fully work. In your example it expands `inc` to the inline function that is within the definition of `inc`. Also, `emit-hygienic-form` is very useful if you want to check for shadowing:

```
(emit-form (analyze '(let [a 1 a a] a)))
;=> (let* [a 1 a a] a)

(emit-hygienic-form (analyze '(let [a 1 a a] a)))
;=> (let* [a__#0 1 a__#1 a__#0] a__#1)
```

At the end of the day, `macroexpand-1` `macroexpand-all` `emit-form` and `emit-hygienic-form` are all useful for debugging clojure macros.

Comment: Cheers =) That will probably come in handy in the future.